# How to write each iteration in state?

Tags: reactjs

How to write each received value of "i" in state?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const arr1 = [
    {
      content: 1,
      content: 2,
      content: 3,
      content: 4
    }
  ];

  const onCreateBlock = () => {
    return arr1.map(i => {
      setItems([...items, i.content]);
    });
  };

  return <div className="App">{onCreateBlock()}</div>;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

It doesn’t work like that, or it writes only the last value, but how to write them in the form: [1, 2, 3, 4]?

Upd:

```js
 const [income, setIncome] = useState([]);
  
  const onPostIncomeData = () => {
 return invoiceList.map(i => {
   setIncome([...income, i.amount]);
        });
    }; 
  
  // Result [1, 1, 1, 1];
  // DB amount: 
  // 4, 3, 2, 1
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The issue is your object declaration is invalid. You're trying to assign the key `content` four values. It'd be like trying to assign the same index of an array 4 times and expecting them all to stick.

Comment: You've updated your code, now show us what `invoiceList` looks like, please.

Answer (score 1):

Change your array to have multiple items, since the key `content` can only be present once for each item.

```
  const arr1 = [
    { content: 1 },
    { content: 2 },
    { content: 3 },
    { content: 4 },
  ];
```

Comment: And if the array is empty? That is, I just want to write each "i" and get such an array - [1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: If the array is empty, then `items` will be empty as well.  Side note - your `onCreateBlock` just updates the state, it doesn't render any HTML.

Comment: But how then to write each iteration in an array? I really don’t understand the language barrier ...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  If you change `arr1` in the code you posted, `items` should end up being `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: I have a database in which there is a table with numbers, I want to write each number in my state [], which is initially empty, and so that after iteration it would be like this - arr1 [200, 320, 120]

My database:
id1: num - 200,
id2: num - 320,
id3: num - 120

Comment: So when you pull your data out of the database, make sure it looks like `arr1` in my answer.  You can change the key `content` to `num` if that makes more sense to you.

Comment: Yes, but only the last element is added, in my case - 120, and it turns out - [120, 120, 120, 120], and not [200, 320, 120]

Comment: Ok, this is difficult to discuss in comments.  Can you please update your question, complete with what you are actually getting from the database?